# Xamarin.UITest package does not have a signature matching the target

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, automation

I am very new in Xamarin and automation mobile testing as well. I created the Xamarin.UITest Cross-Platform Test Project in visual studio and try to run some simple tests for virtual device from  Android Device Manager.

I'm trying to use this, but get the message
'Failed to execute: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w com.android.chrome.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.ClearAppData3 - exit code: 1
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.android.chrome.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.ClearAppData3} from pid=8238, uid=8238 not allowed because package com.android.chrome.test does not have a signature matching the target com.android.chrome

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            return ConfigureApp.Android.InstalledApp("com.android.chrome").StartApp();
        }

        return ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
    }
}
```

What is the reason and how to resolve it?